# how to get value from nameless array of Json

Tags: android

```
String  Result=GET(url);
Log.e("result", "data" + Result);
try{
    //JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Result);
    // JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray();
    //int len= jsonMainNode.length();
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(Result);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

        System.out.println("categoryId : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("FirstName"));
        System.out.println("Title : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("LastName"));
        //System.out.println("songs : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("songs"));
    }
```

Note: I am trying this to get object of nameless array. I am not getting how to store the response as a form of Json object

Comment: Your `try` block is not finished. If it is not relevant to the question, then do not include it. What happens when you run this code? Why do you assume that the array has three elements?

Comment: Please post example JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me.

```
try {
    JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(Result);
    for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobj= jarr.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println("categoryId : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("FirstName"));
        System.out.println("Title : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("LastName"));

    }
}
```

Comment: its no working iam getting response as nameless array